# Dynamically removing a FormControl in a nested form (FormRecord) results in 'No overload matches this call'

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm working with an angular app where I need to dynamically add/remove form controls (checkboxes) in a form record.

I created a minimal version of this behaviour on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l79zu2?file=src%2Fmain.ts), the important stuff is in the code below.

```
private formBuilder = inject(NonNullableFormBuilder);

form = this.formBuilder.record<boolean>({});

nestedForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  field1: [``],
  subRecord: this.formBuilder.record<boolean>({}),
});

// This works without problem
removeRandomFormControls() {
  const record = this.form;
  Object.keys(record.controls).forEach((key) => {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
      return;
    }
    record.removeControl(key, { emitEvent: false });
  });
}

// This is the exact same thing, but in a nested FormRecord. This gives an error.
removeRandomNestedFormControls() {
  const subRecord = this.nestedForm.controls.subRecord;
  Object.keys(subRecord.controls).forEach((key) => {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
      return;
    }
    // The error occurs on the following line
    subRecord.removeControl(key, { emitEvent: false });
  });
}
```

The error that I get is

```
No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(this: FormGroup<{ [key: string]: AbstractControl<any, any>; }>, name: string, options?: { emitEvent?: boolean | undefined; } | undefined): void', gave the following error.
The 'this' context of type 'FormGroup<{ [key: string]: FormControl<boolean>; }>' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'FormGroup<{ [key: string]: AbstractControl<any, any>; }>'.
Type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl<any, any>; }' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: FormControl<boolean>; }'.
'string' index signatures are incompatible.
Type 'AbstractControl<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'FormControl<boolean>': defaultValue, registerOnChange, registerOnDisabledChange
Overload 2 of 2, '(name: never, options?: { emitEvent?: boolean | undefined; } | undefined): void', gave the following error.
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

The interesting things I see are that I can use `addControl()` without issues. Another interesting thing (perhaps what causes this error) is that formBuilder seems to change the type of the nested FormRecord to FormGroup. Meaning that `subRecord` has the type `FormRecord<FormControl<boolean>>`, whereas the whole `nestedForm` has the type

```
FormGroup<{
    field1: FormControl<string>;
    subRecord: FormGroup<{ // <-- not FormRecord?? 
        [key: string]: FormControl<boolean>;     
    }>;
}>
```

Is this a bug in Angular Forms, or am I missing something obvious? How is this supposed to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an inference issue/bug with `FormBuild.group` with doesn't return `subRecord` as `FormRecord`

```
  nestedForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    field1: [``],
    subRecord: this.formBuilder.record<boolean>({}),
  });
```

It's inferred as

```
FormGroup<{
    field1: FormControl<string>;
    subRecord: FormGroup<{
        [key: string]: FormControl<boolean>;
    }>;
}>
```

The easiest fix is to specify the return type of `subRecord`

```
const subRecord: FormRecord<FormControl<boolean>> = this.nestedForm.controls.subRecord;
```